# U-SQL External table error: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'.'

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm failing to create external tables to two specific tables from Azure SQL DB,

I already created few external tables with no issues.
The only difference I can see between the failed and the successful external tables is that the tables that failed contains geography type columns, so I think this is the issue but i'm not sure.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Data].[Devices]
(
    [Id] int
)
FROM SqlDbSource LOCATION "[Data].[Devices]";
```

```
Failed to connect to data source: 'SqlDbSource', with error(s): 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'.'
```

Comment: Please check all the data to see if there are any properties inserted as null in the database.

Comment: @LeonYue I'm taking only 1 column: Id, and it is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing a workaround to the external table:
I created a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/ddl/views) that [select from external rowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/select-selecting-from-an-external-rowset) using EXECUTE

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS [Data].[Devices]
AS 
SELECT Id FROM EXTERNAL SqlDbSource 
EXECUTE "SELECT Id FROM [Data].[Devices]";
```

This made the script to completely ignore the geography type column, which is currently not supported as [REMOTEABLE_TYPE for data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/ddl/data-sources/create-data-source) by U-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my answer on the other thread opened by you. To add to that, I would also recommend you to have a look at how to create a table using a query. In the query, you should be able to use "extractors" in the query to create the tables. To read more about extractors, please have a look at this doc.

Hope this helps.